# ado.net sqlparameter in localize language

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am passing persian text as value of sqlparameter to a parameterized query in asp.net/vb.net
but returns no row - the same query i run in ssms - gives result rows. Don't understand where is the mistake.
Database already collated 'Persian_100_ci_ai.
Vb.net:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand   
     Dim dt As New DataTable  
     Dim dr As SqlDataReader  
     dt.TableName = "temp"  
     Try  
         If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()  
         If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()  
         cmd.Connection = conn  
         Dim qry As String =  "Select * from users WHERE [Name]=@UserName AND [Pwd]=@Password"  
         cmd.commandtext = qry    
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "ادمین"    
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "ادمین"  
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)    
            If dr.HasRows Then  
                dt.Load(dr)  
            End If  

            Return dt  
        Catch ex As Exception  
            Return Nothing  
        Finally  
            dt = Nothing  
            cmd.Connection = Nothing  
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()  
            cmd.Dispose()  
        End Try
```

While in ssms:

```
declare @UserName nvarchar(50) = 'ادمين'
declare @Password nvarchar(50)= 'ادمين'
select * from Users where [name]=@UserName and [Pwd] = @Password
```

Interesting part when in vb.net I create query embedding criteria and not passed as parameter - it works:

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim pLoginName As String = "ادمین"
        Dim pPassword As String = "ادمین"
        dt.TableName = "temp"
        Try
            If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
               Dim qry As String ="Select * from users WHERE [Name]='" & pLoginName & "' AND [Pwd]='" & pPassword & "'"
 cmd.CommandText = qry
           dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dt.Load(dr)
            End If

            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            dt = Nothing
            cmd.Connection = Nothing
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: This is strange. I've never had such a problem. Let me have a look.

Comment: Can you tell me what is those columns' data types?